# Programmatically Display/Change Menu Link

Tags: drupal

When an anonymous user comes to the site, the last item in the Primary Links needs to say Login. However, if they are logged in, it needs to say Account.

Whats the easiest way to achieve this in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I accomplish this by using the [me aliases](http://drupal.org/project/me) module to generate one single path for the account page of the logged in user (e.g. `user/me`) and adding both `user/me` and `user/login` to the menu.

If you wanted to do this programmatically, you'd use [`menu_link_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/menu_link_save/6):

```
$account = array(
  'link_path' => 'user/me',
  'link_title' => t('Account'),
  'weight' => 100,
);

$login = array(
  'link_path' => 'user/login',
  'link_title'=> t('Login'),
  'weight' => 100,
);

menu_link_save($account);
menu_link_save($login);
```

Due to the way Drupal handles menu permissions, a logged in user will not see **Login** (logged in users do not have access to `user/login`) but will see **Account**, and logged out users will see **Login** but won't see **Account** (anonymous users do not have access to `user/me`).

Comment: Wow, that was a lot easier than I thought it would be. Never heard of that module before. Thanks.